# ¿Cómo definir el tamaño de un char en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente codigo y me provoca el error en VS2015

```
int funcion(const char* url) {
    char req[strlen(url) + 31];
}
```

> La llamada de la funcion debe tener un valor constante en una expresion constante.

*strlen* o *sizeof* en este caso  ?

Comment: `strlen( )` no es una constante, es una función.

Comment: @Mr Jhon tu código debería compilar sin problemas, estas ingresando parámetros inadecuados a la hora de llamar la función...

Comment: Si, claro que es una funcion pero el VS lo tomo asi,

Comment: @nikomaster no, el código no debería compilar sin problemas, es normal que falle al menos en C++.

Answer (score 2):

Para inicializar usa `new`

```
int funcion(const char* url) {
    char *req = new char [strlen(url) + 31];
}
```

Si lo quieres inicializar con valores 0:

```
char *req = new char [strlen(url) + 31]();
```

Comment: Gracias!, funciona.

Comment: Encantado de ayudarte.

Comment: Esta respuesta da un código alternativo para que el programa funcione, pero no explica por qué la solución inicial es errónea. El que pregunta podría aprender a que todo lo tiene que hacer con `new` para quitarse de problemas, y más que ayudarlo al final lo malenseñas

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando, sin saberlo, una característica llamada *Arreglo de Tamaño Variable* ([*Variable Lenght Array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) como se conoce en Inglés), traduzco de la Wikipedia:

> En programación, un Arreglo de Tamaño Variable (ATV), es un arreglo de [almacenamiento automático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asignaci%C3%B3n_de_memoria#Asignaci.C3.B3n_autom.C3.A1tica_de_memoria) cuya longitud se determina en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n) (en lugar de en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n)).
>
> Entre los lenguajes que soportan ATV tenemos Ada, Algol 68, APL, C99, C# (en modo no-seguro), COBOL, Fortran 90 y J.

### Uso de Arreglos de Tamaño Variable en C++ y en C

C++ no da soporte a Arreglos de Tamaño Variable de manera nativa, pero algunos compiladores los implementan como extensión del compilador<sup>1</sup>; entre los compiladores que implementan esta extensión [no se encuentra MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx).

En cuanto a C: el estándar C99 soporta los Arreglos de Tamaño Variable, pero a partir del estándar C11<sup>2</sup> dicho soporte pasa a ser opcional.

Por lo tanto, compilando C++ en MSVC tu código:

```
int funcion(const char* url) {
    char req[strlen(url) + 31];
}
```

Es ilegal ya que usas un Arreglo de Tamaño Variable el cuál no tiene soporte en MSVC.

### ¿Cuál es el problema?

En C++ es obligatorio que los arreglos creados en la pila (almacenamiento automático) tengan un tamaño calculable en tiempo de compilación, la expresión que has usado en el tamaño de `req` sólo es calculable en tiempo de ejecución y de ahí que te salte el error:

> ```
> La llamada de la funcion debe tener un valor constante en una expresion constante.
> ```

El valor del puntero `url` sólo es conocido en tiempo de ejecución y en consecuencia la instrucción `strlen(url)` no es calculable en tiempo de compilación y por ello la expresión `strlen(url) + 31` tampoco lo es.

### Posibles soluciones.

#### Usando una función `constexpr`

Crea una función que calcule el tamaño de una cadena (apuntada por un puntero) en tiempo de compilación. Para ello deberás usar [el calificador `constexpr`](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/constexpr-desencadenadas/):

```
constexpr int longitud(const char* cadena) {
    int result{0};

    while (*cadena) {
        ++cadena;
        ++result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Podremos usar la función `longitud` para calcular en tiempo de compilación la longitud de cadenas:

```
std::int8_t arreglo[ longitud("Hola mundo!") + 31 ] {};
std::cout << sizeof arreglo; // muestra 42 (11 + 31)
```

Pero calificar una función con `constexpr` no es garantía de que el compilador vaya a evaluar dicha función en tiempo de compilación, si la función recibe parámetros no conocidos en tiempo de compilación se evaluará en tiempo de ejecución y por lo tanto no sería usable en contextos que requieran expresiones constantes:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // error de compilacion *argv no es conocido en tiempo compilacion
    std::int8_t arreglo[ longitud(*argv) + 31 ] {};
    return 0;
}
```

#### Usando `std::vector`

También puedes abandonar la idea de usar un arreglo y pasar a usar un [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
int funcion(const char* url) {
    std::vector<char> req(strlen(url) + 31);
}
```

Dependiendo del uso que le des a `req` posteriormente, deberás hacer algunos cambios a tu código para que la solución con `std::vector` funcione.

---

<sup>1</sup>Entre los más populares y usados tenemos [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) y [llvm](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla),

<sup>2</sup>C99 es más antiguo que C11, el número no se corresponde con la versión si no con el año de aprobación. Así pues C99 es de 1999 mientras que C11 es de 2011.